# Is this query to retrieve data from database correct?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to retrieve a value from a field in database. I have the used following code. but the value `checkOrderId` (which I need) shows the SQL string instead of the value from database. I don't know why it is doing so. Could somebody help me please?

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source = xxyyzz;Initial Catalog = xyz; Integrated Security = True";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();

string tableName = "[GIS].[SecondaryTraffic].[PotentialBackHauls]";

string checkOrderId = "Select TOP 1 OrderID From" + tableName + "ORDER BY InsertDate DESC";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkOrderId, connection);

//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client popConn = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
if (orderIdentity == checkOrderId)
{
      popConn.DeleteMessage(messageNumber);
}

connection.Close();
```

I am new and dont have reputation to answer my question immediately. With everybody's help, i got this one solved...Great help, thanx everybody...following is my code.

string connectionString = "Data Source = EAEDEV;Initial Catalog = GIS; Integrated Security = True";

```
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {


                        connection.Open();

                        string tableName = "[GIS].[SecondaryTraffic].[PotentialBackHauls]";

                        string checkOrderId = "Select TOP 1 OrderID From " + tableName + " ORDER BY InsertDate DESC";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkOrderId, connection);


                        string valueReturned = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                        OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client popConn = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();

                        if (orderIdentity == valueReturned)
                        {
                            popConn.DeleteMessage(messageNumber);
                        }

                        connection.Close();


                    }
```

Comment: you need to execute the command and retrieve the result. See the [documentaation for SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) for a full example

Comment: Or can use DataReader instead of ExecuteNonQueey.

Comment: In addition to what others are saying, you really should wrap the connection in a using block.

Comment: Maraduarz, you should accept one of the answers. Both are looking correct, so I gave them +1.

Comment: He doesn't need to use using block. He is closing connectio at the end but should use try catch block and to put the connection.Close() in a finally block

Comment: @Nick At which point you may as well have used the `using` block, so the "need" for it is arguably the same as your suggestion.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth True but not mandatory. That was the point of the comment. But he does have to execute command.

Comment: @Nick I know it isn't mandatory, but you just implied that the try/finally *was* mandatory.

Comment: Thank you guys, like Nick said, simplest thing that would meet my purpose here would be to use SQLDataReader. It was really quick. I had spent a good amount of time and could not realize it. I am still learning.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth There is no point in arguing abot it you are totally right. Using will close the connection but won't catch any exception.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the query and check the results, here you are just comparing a string with the query SQL.

Please see here

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson03

for a tutorial.

Comment: thanx, i'm going through it at the moment.

Comment: the tutorial was  a great help, it helped me not only get this done but understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation of the result being set into `checkOrderId` is incorrect. In this instance `checkOrderId` is just the query to execute and not the actual result.

You need to read the value back from executing the command:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand("Select TOP 1 OrderID From [GIS].[SecondaryTraffic].[PotentialBackHauls] ORDER BY InsertDate DESC", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    object result = comm.ExecuteScalar(); // This is the key bit you were missing.

    if (result != null)
    {
        // You can cast result to something useful
        int orderId = (int)result;
    }
} // Both comm and connection will have Dispose called on them here, no need to Close manually.
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns the value in the first cell (ie, column 1 row 1) as an object that you can cast to a better type (depending on what type it was in the result-set schema).

If you need to read multiple values, you need to look at `ExecuteReader`.

There are also other ways of doing this using output parameters, but that would pollute the point of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add space to your query

```
"Select TOP 1 OrderID From " + tableName + " ORDER BY InsertDate DESC";
```

Nota : I suggest you to use `AddWithValue method` with your parameter

```
string checkOrderId = "Select TOP 1 OrderID From @tableName ORDER BY InsertDate DESC";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkOrderId, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableName );
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx

Comment: It's not just the missing space.  The posted code doens't actually execute the query.

Comment: @Candie, thank you. I will try your suggestion. See if it words, because it is still not returning the value.

Comment: i'am happy to help you Maraduarz

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually run your command anywhere.  Instead of the commented-out `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, you should look into the [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method, which allows you to read back a single result value from a query - which is what your query returns.

Comment: i found out later what the differences were. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
int i = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

right after

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkOrderId, connection);
```

then the variable `i` will contain the order id

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct. You are comparing the variable orderId to your query string. I doubt that's what you want to do. I imagine you'd be better off calling cmd.ExecuteScalar() to retrieve the actual OrderID value. As noted by other answers, your query string is missing a space. But most importantly, it is bad practice to construct SQL queries in code. Although I can't see a security issue with this code, if you continue to use this method you will probably write code that is vulnerable to SQL injection. I recommend you learn to either use parameters or LINQ to build your queries.

Comment: yes you are right. I realized it only after going through above posts. I am still new and learning. Thank you:)